# Multi-sign transaction is not working

Tags: stellar-core, java-sdk, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory, multi-sig

I am creating a multi-sign transaction. When I am submitting the transaction to Stellar, `response.isSuccess()` returns `false`. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong? link https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#multi-signature-account

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Network.useTestNetwork();
    Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");

    KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed("SC4EJSKMHQLHRUWFYC7O62OP2QPQ2HD7IOXCHKR2STVPAQ6E5MBXXRAI");

    KeyPair source1 = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed("SCR5ARAIDZ6EW4NRVFUP35CY444S3D4H52GIVKW46D736UFFVQFLLVY4");
    KeyPair secondary1 = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GAU3GFO7L3TECSZ2ARAHACTQ44QKHKU355PHWBLRIWHXIDXBRHMNOYVQ");

    KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GCFOSKTU4N4OPOXFGA473V2DG36QBCHNPHXOLU4W2BZL5TZH4GCZS5BN");

    try {
        server.accounts().account(destination);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    AccountResponse sourceAccount = null;
    try {
        sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source);
        sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
            .addOperation(new SetOptionsOperation.Builder().setSigner(secondary1.getXdrSignerKey(), 1)
                    .setMasterKeyWeight(1).setLowThreshold(0)
                    .setMediumThreshold(2).setHighThreshold(2).build())
            .build();
    transaction.sign(source);
    transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
            .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), "11").build())
            .addMemo(Memo.text("Test Transaction"))
            .build();

    transaction.sign(source);
    transaction.sign(source1);
    try {
        SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);

        System.out.println(response.isSuccess());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because of a bad sequence number. I know this because I decoded `response.getResultXdr()`. Here are some things you should know:

1. When you call `sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source)`, `sourceAccount` will have the correct sequence number.
2. When you call `build()`, the `TransactionBuilder` will increment the account's sequence number by 1, so that the account is ready to participate in a new transaction
3. Because you never submit the first transaction, that sequence number is never used.
4. When you reassign `transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)`, `sourceAccount` has the incremented sequence number.
5. When you submit the second `transaction`, the network rejects it because it never received the preceding sequence number.

Although I'm not sure what you're trying to do, you need to make sure that you call `build` once before calling `submitTransaction`.

Comment: thanks for response , what am trying to do mean, please referrer that link and sample code   https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#multi-signature-account